# set selected row in ag-grid-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found *ag-grid-react* is quite handy to render Grid.

I ran into trouble that I can not find api of the grid to set selected rows.

the gridApi has an API: `getSelectedRows()` so I assumed that there is an API to achieve what I wanted.

- **OS:** Window 10
- **Package Manager:** npm, yarn
- **AG Grid version:** 25.1.0
- **Language:** ES6/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to select the rows I wanted using forEachNode and setSelected from gridApi:

*setSelected(newValue: boolean, clearSelection: boolean)*

```
  gridApi.forEachNode((rowNode) => {
    if (*condition*) {
      rowNode.setSelected(true, false);
    } else {
      rowNode.setSelected(false, false);
    }
  });
```

But I still have 1 more problem of setting rowNode.data, set rowNode.data not rerender the row itself. I'm using *agRichSelectCellEditor* to edit cell. The row has the data but not rerender. I have to click on it again to render the valueFormat